# Read/Store iPhone documents in my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, documents

I am working to create an iPhone app to `store documents` from the device(iPhone/iPod Touch). My idea is to keep the files, documents in the app which from the `Mac -> Device (iPhone/iPod Touch) -> iPhone app`. I know to transfer the documents from Mac to iPhone device. I confused and i dont have any idea to read the documents from the device to my app. I have used Google to find the answer and found the way to sync the device with mac and transfer the documents to device. But, i can't find the solution to store the device documents to my app. I want to store all type of documents in my app (Eg: `PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, PPT, PPTX, HTML, HTM, TXT, TEXT, RTF, RTFD, LOG, CPP, C, WEBARCHIVE, H, M, MM`). It is possible?.

Can you please help and suggest me we can do this. How to read the documents from Mac -> iPhone app. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to read the contents of these files?  If so, then you will need to handle each file type individually.  I'm not sure you will find a generic solution that will enable you to read all of these file types.  However, if you just need to store them in the iOS filesystem, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an existing file service such as DropBox. Their SDK is available here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk

It's the fastest way to have iOS devices synchronize files and with support for desktop and web as well.

iCloud is also an option.